# How do I find numerical solutions to geodesics when given initial four-position, initial four-velocity and a metric? (for a ray tracer)

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, simulations, geodesics

I've had the idea to try and code a ray tracer that obeys laws of special/general relativity. In order to predict the motion of objects in the scene I'd need to compute geodesics with a user specified metric. How can I do this in the most efficient way.

Lets take the Schwarzschild metric for example. Assume the observer in the simulation is very far away from the origin (point of view the user would see). Every time step in the simulation would correspond to a step in proper time for the observer. So for every time step how can I update the positions/velocities of objects in the scene such that they obey relativity, and as time passes the objects follow well approximated time like geodesic paths.

That would be for test particles such as planets or asteroids. Since this is a ray tracer I  would also like to simulate light as accurately as possible. So as an extension, how would I compute light like geodesics.

Comment: For the Schwarzschild metric use the geodesic equation from [Output 8](http://relativity.yukterez.net/06.html#8) for the acceleration and [Output 11](http://relativity.yukterez.net/06.html#11) for the initial conditions. With that you can calculate the trajectories like [here](https://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=554#p554) and raytrace like [here](https://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?t=94). μ=0 is for photons and μ=-1 for particles.